# Why does url_for() works with 'static' as first parameter? There's no static()

Tags: python, flask

Can't understand why it does work, so I can't change it:

I'm using Flask-Admin's `ImageUploadField` in a form, the field is this:

```
image = ImageUploadField(label='Optional image',
                         base_path=app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],
                         relative_path=op.relpath(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER']),
                         endpoint='static'
                         )
```

`endpoint='static'` is the default value.

`endpoint` is used in `flask_admin.ext.form.upload` this way:

```
def get_url(self, field):
    if field.thumbnail_size:
        filename = field.thumbnail_fn(field.data)
    else:
        filename = field.data

    if field.url_relative_path:
        filename = urljoin(field.url_relative_path, filename)
    return url_for(field.endpoint, filename=filename)
```

So it's being passed to an `url_for()` function...

the result of that `url_for()` is just prepending `'static/'` to the filename. If I try to set

```
endpoint='some_string'
```

of course it raises a `BuildError`, but if I try to do:

```
#admin.py
class ProductForm(Form):
    order = IntegerField('order')
    name = TextField('name')
    category = SelectField('category', choices=[])
    image = ImageUploadField(label='Optional image',
                             base_path=app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],
                             relative_path=op.relpath(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER']),
                             endpoint='dumb_f'
                             )
def dumb_f(str=''):
    return str
```

It raises the `BuildError` as well, I guess because `dumb_f()` is not visible in `upload.py`.

Why does `url_for()` even work? Shouldn't the first parameter be the name of a function? I have no `static` named method, nor does `upload.py` have one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flask provides the `static` *endpoint* for you.

Note that I used the word *endpoint* there; the `url_for()` function takes an endpoint name, and the `@app.route()` decorator *defaults* to using the function name as the endpoint name, but you are in no way *required* to use the function name.

Your code is not the only place routes and endpoints can be registered. The Flask app simply registered `static` when you created it, based on the default configuration.

See the [`Flask` class definition source code](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/blob/master/flask/app.py#L520-L523):

```
# register the static folder for the application.  Do that even
# if the folder does not exist.  First of all it might be created
# while the server is running (usually happens during development)
# but also because google appengine stores static files somewhere
# else when mapped with the .yml file.
if self.has_static_folder:
    self.add_url_rule(self.static_url_path + '/<path:filename>',
                      endpoint='static',
                      view_func=self.send_static_file)
```

The [`app.add_url_rule()` method](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Flask.add_url_rule) registers a route too, and Flask specifies the `endpoint` argument explicitly here.

If you want to serve uploaded images from a different endpoint, you'll have to register one yourself.